# Can I deploy only artifact with Maven?

Tags: java, maven, deployment

Is it possible with maven to deploy only created artifact?
I tried to do it with deploy:deploy-file directive, but I obtained the classic deploy result with

- maven-metadata.xml, sha1 and md5
- StormWithKafkaSpout-1.0-20140918.101702-1.pom sha1 and md5
- StormWithKafkaSpout-1.0-20140918.101702-1.zip with sha1 and md5

Among these 3 files I'm only interested into deploying
StormWithKafkaSpout-1.0-20140918.101702-1.zip and I don't want to produce any sha1 or md5 file.

Moreover, I'd like do deploy that file in a specific folder (we say "specificFolder") in my repository and not in "specificFolder"/com/blabla/StormWithKafkaSpout/1.0-SNAPSHOT directory where now I found all these files.

This is the command I give to deploy:

```
deploy:deploy-file -Dfile=/root/NetBeansProjects/StormWithKafkaSpout/target/StormWithKafkaSpout-1.0-SNAPSHOT-bin.zip -Durl=scp://IP/home/stormuser -DrepositoryId=stormPC -DgroupId=com.blabla -DartifactId=StormWithKafkaSpout -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=zip
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Try [deploy-file](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/usage.html).

Comment: I do it as I say in the last raw I write: I type "mvn deploy:deploy-file -Dfile=/root/NetBeansProjects/StormWithKafkaSpout/target/StormWithKafkaSpout-1.0-SNAPSHOT-bin.zip -Durl=scp://IP/home/stormuser -DrepositoryId=stormPC -DgroupId=com.blabla -DartifactId=StormWithKafkaSpout -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=zip"